# how to tweak XCode Organizer GUI?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've just noticed that I can't read the Creation and Expiration dates of profiles in the Xcode Organizer. I don't seem able to change the width of these gui fields in organizer and the dates display as 14/03/... instead of 14/03/13 for example.

Comment: What is your version of XCode ?

Comment: Please try once restarting your system....

Comment: I'm on Version 4.3.1 and a restart doesn't help. I can resize the width of the name field and the status field, but not the others.

Comment: I've been really annoyed by this bug also. I suggest filing a radar about it.

Comment: Thanks Matt for letting me know I'm not going crazy, have submitted a radar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found is:
 - press CTRL and select the profile with mouse (you should get menu)
 - select Reveal Profile in Finder (works only with profiles in the Library, not stored on the device)
 - open the profile in Finder with Other... and select TextEdit

The creation date is visible once opened in TextEdit.

For profiles stored on the phone you can of course open Settings -> General -> Profiles -> particular profile and view the date there.

**Edit: Ah, just found the hidden shortcut in XCode. Simply however over the date and press left Shift.**

Comment: Thanks for finding that shortcut, it makes things a little less irksome :)

Comment: No probs, pls consider marking as the answer if it resolved your issue :)